# $\tau_k(\omega)=\inf \{n>\tau_{k-1} : |Y_n(\omega)-Y(\omega)|\leq 1/k\}$ is measurable?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $Y_1,\,Y_2\ldots$ be a sequence of real random variables and $Y(\omega)=\liminf_{n\to\infty}Y_n(\omega)\in R$. I define using ricursion the sequenze $\tau_k(\omega)=\inf \{n>\tau_{k-1} : |Y_n(\omega)-Y(\omega)|\leq 1/k\}$ and I want to prove that $\tau_k$ is measurable. Can anyone give me any idea? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach is to induct on $k$. $\tau_k$ is a random variable taking values in $\mathbb{N}$, so "$\tau_k$ is measurable" means that given any Borel subset $A$ of $\mathbb{N}$, we must have $\tau_k^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{F}$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is the sigma algebra of the domain of $\tau_k$. To simplify the task, note that sets of the form $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ form a $\pi$-system generating the Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb{N}$, so it's sufficient to check that $\tau_k^{-1}(\{1,\ldots,n\}) \in \mathcal{F}$ for each integer $n$.

But $\tau_k^{-1}(\{1,\ldots,n\}) = \{\tau_k \leq n\}$. From here, note that $\{\tau_k \leq n\}=\{\tau_k \leq n, \tau_{k-1} \leq n\}$, and we can now write this event as the union of events where $\tau_k$ and $\tau_{k-1}$ take particular values from $1$ to $n$. By the inductive hypothesis $\tau_{k-1}$ is measurable, and you should be able to write the events of the form $\{\tau_k = j, \tau_{k-1} = m\}$ as the intersection of events of the form $\{\tau_{k-1} = m\}$ and $\{|Y_j-Y|>1/n\}$, which we know to be measurable. The base case will be a similar argument to the above.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $k$ and let $I_n = \{ \omega | |Y_n(\omega)-Y(\omega)|\leq 1/k\} $, for $n = r_{k-1}+1, r_{k-1}+2, ...$.

Let $\Delta_{r_{k-1}+1} = I_{r_{k-1}+1}$, and $\Delta_n = I_n \setminus (I_{n-1} \cup \cdots \cup I_{r_{k-1}+1})$.
for $n >r_{k-1}+1$.

Let $\phi_k = \sum_{m=r_{k-1}+1}^\infty m 1_{\Delta_m}$. Then $r_k = \phi_k$.

(Possibly you might want to define $\phi_k(\omega) =  +\infty$ when $\omega \notin \cup_{m=r_{k-1}+1}^\infty I_m$.)